# Pocket PC not Connecting to PC

Tags: sdk, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I have a Symbol PPT8800 that will not connect to Windows Mobile Device Center.  It was working, I took it off the cradle, did a hard reset, and now it's not connecting.  Is there a setting on the HH itself that is preventing the connection?

I have other Symbol PPT8800's that will connect in the same cradle without an issue.

Comment: Device Center should recognize the mobile device when it is plugged in. If not, perhaps something on the device is damaged. Why did you have to do a Hard Reset anyway?

Comment: To Re-install .NET Framework

Comment: What is HH? Hand Held?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possible sources for connection problems between a windows mobile handheld device and a PC running WMDC (ActiveSync).

1. use a known good USB cable
2. connect USB cable directly into PC and avoid USB hub
3. verify WMDC connects with another windows mobile device
4. disconnect handheld and reboot you PC and wait until PC is booted
   before trying to  connect
5. "Allow USB connections" has been deselected in WMDC Connection
   Settings
6. sometimes the device setting "Enable advanced network functionality"
   in Start/Settings/Connections/"USB to PC" has to be unchecked (or
   checked).
7. the device has a corrupted registry and does not start the connect
   (repllog.exe) or does not authenticate correctly. Do a clean boot or
   wipe of the device to get the device back to factory defaults

I am sorry, but there are many possible issues that can cause a WMDC connection to fail. Recently I had the prob that after sleep/resume of my PC the USB hubs were in power save mode and I was unable to get device to connect to WMDC.

Does your PC do some 'boing' sound when you attach the USB cable to the device?
What does Hardware Device Manager show? Any exclamation marks?

EDIT: How to wipe a device?
You need to write either a small .net or c++ app using [DMProcessConfigXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158518.aspx) and the following wap provisioning xml:

```
<wap-provisioningdoc>
  <characteristic type="RemoteWipe">
     <parm name="doWipe" value="1"/>
  </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

[see also http://peterfoot.net/UsingRemoteWipe.aspx]

or use RapiConfig tool from [Mobile SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb737283.aspx).

If both are not useable for you (is that running Windows Mobile or Windows CE?) or just restore factory default or [reflash](http://software.symbol.com/detail.cfm?prod=1799) the device. If it is a device with Windows Mobile before version 5, you can just do a cold boot but delete any persistent folder first (ie Flash File Store or ???).

Factory [restore of PT 8800](http://www.exactsoftware.com/docs/DocView.aspx?DocumentID=%7B819d0083-0977-4be6-81dc-b2db242d86c0%7D):

```
 hold white RESET button + POWER + FUNC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have the 2 HH in question on multiple computers it authenticates on the HH shows "Connecting" on the PC's however eventually just shows "Not Connected" It is a serial connection (Old PPT8800) so there is not a sound the PC makes.  On the HH it shows "Connected" to the computer... seems like  #7 is the issue... However, I have no idea how to do a clean boot, or how to wipe it (These are Point-Of-Sale) HH that our POS company sends us.

Comment: The other important piece of information is, Other HH are connecting fine.

Comment: Why would "Allow USB connections" be deselected?

Comment: That PC setting "Allow USB connections" maybe accidently de-selected (that was a list of possible casues). The other one, "Start/Settings/Connections/"USB to PC" is on device.